# How to use Laravel's Input::hasFile on a file in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I'm wondering if it's possible to check if I have a file uploaded even if it's in an array

Consider this

```
Array
(
[files] => Array
    (
        [cv] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
            (
                [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
                [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => CV.docx
                [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
                [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 24811
                [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
                [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/phpStNPZE
                [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpStNPZE
            )

        [interview_questionaire] => 
        [application_form] => 
        [doctors_details] => 
        [t_and_c] =>  
    ...
```

Would it be possible if I have files[cv] ?

I have tried Input::hasFile("files[cv]") and also Input::hasFile("cv") but neither worked

The reason I ask is because I am looping through `files` and some of them are blank, and I only want to proceed if it has a file

Comment: Try with ***Input::file("files")['cv']*** instead.

Comment: Or Input::hasFile("files.cv")